# RichTextBox line equal to a string

Tags: string, vb.net, richtextbox

I need to state a behaviour of my software when a line of a richtextbox is equal to a string setted by me. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    For i = 0 To ListBox14.Items.Count - 2
        If RichTextBox1.Lines(ListBox14.Items(i) + 1) = crt Then
            Label18.Text = (ListBox14.Items(i) + 1).ToString()
        End If
    Next
```

where the Listbox14 contains the index of the previous lines I have to test and crt is the string to be compared with the RTB lines. When I try this, during debugging, I'm receiving an error about out of bounds. How could I solve? Thanks all are gonna answer me. Best regards

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to mean "RichTextBox1.Lines(ListBox14.Items(i) + 1) "  I think the 1st thing you need to do is turn Option Strict on because that just looks plain wrong to me. And can I ask, why Count - 2, then add 1 back on when accessing the items?

Comment: A ListBox item is an Object. You can't add one to an object. Even if you convert the object to a number type and add one, you can't compare a number to a String. OPTION STRICT ON! as @Hursey said.